# is there a way to make a Forking in Git and then maintaining or merging from original project?

Tags: git, open-source, github, git-fork

I want to take an open source project (A) from GitHub,  fork it to my account and then make some modifications (B).

Then after a while, there will be changes on the original (A) repository and at the same time I did changes on my repository (B)

The question is:  is there a way then to maintain or merge from repo (A) to repo (B) ?

and the other question is:  is a good idea?  I know it depends on what type of changes I make to the source code,  but is this a good practice,  or usually when there is forking, projects go in very different ways ?

Thanks

Comment: Is your question about github's capabilities or git's? You can most certainly do this in git. You just add remotes, as Michael said below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the repository you forked from as a remote

```
git remote add upstream PATH_TO_REPO
```

Then you can just

```
get fetch upstream
git merge upstream/BRANCH_NAME
```